# Retagging questions

Tags: bug, status-norepro, tags, suggested-edits

I tried to retag [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/15965/4012). Although I have over the 200 rep so I can retag, it has been marked for peer review.

Have the boundaries changed and the faq hasn't been updated to reflect it?

Comment: There's a similar report already opened on [here on Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77798/suggesting-new-tags-might-be-bugged), but in that instance the user is on a Beta site *and* it's about creating tags. Because our privileges are different as Stack Exchange 2.0, I'm going to keep this here for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have little enough rep to see, but perhaps there is both an "edit" and "retag" option, and you used the edit one rather than the retag one?

Comment: This is the case when you have between the retag reputation and the full edit reputation. I don't know if it's the culprit here, but I will confirm that this is behavior that does happen.

Comment: I've run into this issue before, and the problem was that I'd hit 'edit' instead of 'retag'.

Comment: Yes - on sites where I have enough rep to retag but not to edit I see both the "edit" and "retag" links.

Answer (score 1):

We think you clicked edit instead of retag here.